# How two prevent loading apple map and to start with OSM MKTileOverlay

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I need to display OSM overlays instead of standard apple maps in mapkit framework. But I have an issue, how can I display OSM overlay without loading apple maps? Now I just have a method

```
AxMapKitTileOverlay *mapOverlay = [[AxMapKitTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:URLTemplate];
[self.mapView addOverlay:mapOverlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];
```

which is loading tiled overlay - but if I run it during the map initialization - the map didn't changed, and when I use this method later - I get apple default map loaded.

Maybe I should react on some delegate method? How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you see the tiles at all? Have you tried setting `mapOverlay.canReplaceMapContent = YES;`

Comment: @Onato I firstly see the apple tiles, than I see my osm tiles when I execute method to add overlay on map.

Comment: @Onato I see the tiles, but I want to understand, when should I add the overlay to prevent the appearing of the standard Apple tiles

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the MapKit maps from being drawn set [canReplaceMapContent](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKTileOverlay_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKTileOverlay/canReplaceMapContent) which comes from `MKTileOverlay`

> If the tile content you provide can cover the entire drawing area with opaque content, set this property to YES. Doing so serves as a hint to the map view that it does not need to draw any additional content underneath your tiles. Set this property to NO if your tiles contain any transparency.

The best place to do this is probably in your `viewDidLoad` method. That way it will happen before the user sees anything.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are implementing the `-[MKMapViewDelegate mapView:rendererForOverlay:]` method for the overlay that you are adding or it won't actually get drawn.